# Get data from UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, cocoa, uiimage

I would like to print details such as the ISO, date taken, resolution etc. of a UIImage and print them onto the console using NSLog and I was wondering if there's any frameworks that would allow me to get the 'meta' of a UIImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be of some help for you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001399